# How to write a gvim-help-doc-like text file?

Tags: vim

gvim help doc contains "links",I can jump to subject by hit ctrl+]
How to format a text which can functioning like that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a section in the help dedicated to that topic : **"Writing help files"**

See `: help help-writing` or `:help helphelp.txt`

Excerpt :

```
TAGS


To define a help tag, place the name between asterisks (*tag-name*). 

(...)

When referring to an existing help tag and to create a hot-link, place the
name between two bars (|) eg. |help-writing|.
```

To get more details, please read the previously mentioned help files.

Answer (score 5):

Vim's help files exist in $VIMRUNTIME/doc, so if you view these files and set

```
set syntax=off
```

this will give you an idea of the mark-up. Basically you create links by enclosing them in pipes:

```
go to a link |here|
```

which will jump to an occurrence of the link text enclosed in asterisks, i.e. `*here*`.

Then you just need to do

```
set filetype=help
```

for your files, which you can achieve with an autocommand.

Answer (score 1):

It is required to run command:

```
:helpt[ags] {dir}
```

to generate new tags after file is created. Details can be found:

```
:help helpt
```